# ReCaptcha 2.0: Enable 'Submit' button on callback if recaptcha successful

Tags: javascript, next.js, recaptcha

Trying to enable a 'Submit' button when Google ReCaptacha successfully verifies a user, but it says 'ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user provided function: enableSubmit'.
Google Recaptcha would verify correctly a user, but the 'Submit' button is still disabled on callback. I've tried using `data-callback={enableSubmit}` but it's also not working. I know the enableSubmit() function works since when I call it in CaptchaForm, it'll enable the Button, just not when it's being called in the data-callback.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha'; // eslint says it's not being used
  function enableSubmit() {
  const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit-button');
  submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
}
const CaptchaForm = () => {
return (
      <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.google.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.gstatic.com" crossOrigin="true" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <form method="POST">
          <div
            className="g-recaptcha"
            data-sitekey="SITEKEY"
            data-callback="enableSubmit"
          ></div>
            <Button type={'submit'} id="submit-button" disabled>
              Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
      </body>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you share your imports at the top of the file please

Comment: Added; also added some more comments. I'm not currently using the ReCAPTCHA package, since I thought a simple API call would be sufficient based on the Google Documentation. @Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via two different methods..

The reason your current code isnt working is a simple solution

```
<Button type={'submit'} id="submit-button" disabled>
     Submit
</Button>
```

You have a upper case `B` on your `<button` this means its a component but you don't seem to have a import for `Button`.

All you would need to change would be this

```
<button type={'submit'} id="submit-button" disabled>
     Submit
</button>
```

2nd method

A cleaner method would look something like this using states.

```
import { useState } from "react";
const CaptchaForm = () => {
const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(true)
return (
      <head>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.google.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.gstatic.com" crossOrigin="true" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <form method="POST">
          <div
            className="g-recaptcha"
            data-sitekey="SITEKEY"
            data-callback={() => setButtonDisabled(false)}
          ></div>
            <button type={'submit'} id="submit-button" disabled={buttonDisabled}>
              Submit
            </button>
        </form>
      </body>
  );
};
```